# Seurat with normalized count matrix?

Tags: r, seurat

I know that in `Seurat` we have the function `CreateSeuratObject` from which the analysis starts, but it accepts raw count matrix according to the documentation. I have only the already normalized count matrix, so is there a way to work with `Seurat` using normalized data? I would try maybe to feed in the normalized data instead of raw to `CreateSeuratObject`, but I do not know what `Seurat` is doing behind the scenes, whether it is a good idea. Besides, `Seurat` provides by default only one `log` - normalization method, but I may want to normalize the data by myself with various methods and only then start the analysis with `Seurat` - that is the other reason why I want to find a way to start from normalized data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was addressed by the Seurat developers [here](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/668):

> if you have TPM counts, I suggest you don't use
>   Seurat::NormalizeData(), since TPM counts are already normalized for
>   sequencing depth and transcript/gene length. Note that
>   Seurat::NormalizeData() normalizes the data for sequencing depth, and
>   then transforms it to log space. If you have TPM data, you can simply
>   manually log transform the gene expression matrix in the object@data
>   slot before scaling the data.

And [here](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/481):

> If you want to run your own normalization function, please place the
>   data in log scale before placing it into object@data

And [here](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/171):

> If you're supplying already normalized values to CreateSeuratObject,
>   you should skip the normalization step. You will likely see a warning
>   when you run ScaleData (which is checking whether you normalized using
>   Seurat). You can ignore this or turn it off by setting check.for.norm
>   to FALSE.

This is a lot of quotes, but I found them all to be helpful in different ways.